# Ошибка FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists при открытии файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

```py
def module():
    redak = open (str(input("Как называется файл?: ")), "x")
    redak.write (str(input("На какой текст хотите поменять?: ")))
    redak.close()  
     
if __name__== "__main__":
    L = str(input("Форматировать текст?"))
    if L == "Да" or "+":
        module()
```

При выполнении кода выплывает такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    module()
  File "test.py", line 2, in module
    redak = open (str(input("Как называется файл?: ")), "x")
  FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'b.txt'
```

Comment: вы открываете файл с флагом `"x"`, хотя он уже существует

Comment: Еще... это выражение `if L == "Да" or "+"` не работает так как вы хотели. `"+"` всегда вернет `True`, т.к. это не пустая строка, поэтому ваше выражение это `L == "Да" or True`, а это всегда `True`. Вам нужно проверять так: `if L == "Да" or L == "+"`, а лучше так: `if L in ["Да", "+"]`

Comment: Благодарю, заработало.

Comment: На счет этого выражения, я знаю. Я это сделал для теста.

Answer (score 2):

1. Не нужно конвертировать строку на строку (трижды в вашей программе) - функция `input()`
   возвращает прямо строку, значит, применение функции `str()` не нужно.
2. Второй параметр функции `open()` у вас `"x"` - это значит, что при попытке открыть уже существующий файл выдается ошибка, которую вы получили.

   Существуют 2 решения вашей проблемы:

   1. Нужно задать имя файла, который еще не существует.
   2. Вместо `"x"` применить `"w"` (опасно, т.к. вы можете потерять важной файл) или `"a"` (тоже опасно, но менее, т.к. вы можете изменить важной файл).

Comment: Благодарю, что указали мне на ошибки )

Answer (score 0):

Исправление нескольких ошибок в вашем коде:

```py
def module():
    redak = open (str(input("Как называется файл?: ")), "w") # "w" откроет файл на запись
                                                             # Если такого файла нет,
                                                             # он будет создан
    redak.write (str(input("На какой текст хотите поменять?: ")))
    redak.close()  


if __name__== "__main__":
    L = str(input("Форматировать текст?"))
    # Интерпретатор читает 'L == "Да" or "+"' как (L == "Да") или ("+"). Это всегда будет истинно
    if L in ("Да", "+"): # Если L есть среди "Да", "+"
        module()
```